# Error Object Object using angular2 material datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I've a problem with datepicker and Angular2 Material.

When I tried to use this control, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
```

I have the references done at app_module, I took the original code from official material web: [Date Picker Examples Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples).

```html
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I tried to reproduce and got the error:
Error: "MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter
documented at https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings
Adding MatNativeDateModule to material imported modules worked for me.